# Random generation of elliptic curve points: is there a preferred approach?

Tags: public-key, secp256k1, random, unit-test

While most practical applications are concerned with the random generation of private keys, anyone who wishes to write unit-testing code on the `secp256k1` elliptic curve group may wish to have the ability to randomly generate elliptic curve points.

I can immediately think to two approaches for doing so, one consisting in returning the elliptic point associated with a random secret, the other consisting in randomly generating `X`, computing `X^3 + 7` until we obtain a quadratic residue mod `p` and compute a square root (which reduces to taking a power `(p+1)/4` mod `p` since `p = 3 mod 4`). I am suspecting that the latter approach is computationally more efficient as it does not involve the scalar multiplication of the EC group, but only arithmetic operations and exponentiation mod `p`. Is there a known preferred approach to this question? Assuming my intuition is right, and generating `X` until `X^3 + 7` is a quadratic residue is the way to go, another question naturally arises: what is the preferred approach to test whether a number mod `p` has a square root? Is it worth implementing the Legendre symbol, or is it better to simply check whether the prospective square root (raising to the power `(p+1)/4`) fits the bill?

Early optimization is the root of all evil, so maybe I shouldn't be asking this question, especially as the performance of unit testing code probably doesn't matter. But I figure that if some elements of best practice are known regarding bitcoin development, I may as well adopt them and do the right thing.